# Scoping to a DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm just trying to clean up some jQuery, and can't quite figure out what the call is to scope jQuery calls to a specific dom element. To give an example, I have the following code:

```
$('#outer-element .first-class').html('wanna');
$('#outer-element .second-class').html('scope');
$('#outer-element .third-class').html('better');
```

I'm guessing calling each of those first/second/third-class calls to one common outer-element call is a more elegant approach, I'm just not sure what the syntax is to do that. I'm guessing something along the lines of

```
$('#outer-element').SOMETHINGGOESHERE(function() {
  $(this).find('.first-class').html('wanna');
  $(this).find('.second-class').html('scope');
  $(this).find('.third-class').html('better');
});
```

Any ideas? Anything more elegant than what I've suggested above? In short - I know the above is ugly. I'm looking for a prettier approach to JavaScript like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store the object in a variable and find it inside the cached object

```
var $this = $('#outer-element');

  $this.find('.first-class').html('wanna');
  $this.find('.second-class').html('scope');
  $this.find('.third-class').html('better');
```

Answer (score 5):

As long as the amount of code is manageable, I usually chain everything together with interspersed [`.end()`](http://api.jquery.com/end/) calls:

```
$('#outer-element')
    .find('.first-class').html('wanna').end()
    .find('.second-class').html('scope').end()
    .find('.third-class').html('better').end();
```

If you do things this way you have to be ultra careful to include exactly one `.end()` for each traversing operation; for this reason it might be a good idea to go beyond the call of duty by using whitespace in a manner that reminds of Python:

```
$('#outer-element')
    .find('.first-class')
        .html('wanna')
    .end()
    .find('.second-class')
        .html('scope')
    .end()
    .find('.third-class')
        .html('better')
    .end();
```

The last `.end()` is not necessary, but it might be in the future if the code is modified. Better safe than sorry.

Comment: Just wondering.  Is there a reason to use this method over the other 2 answers?

Comment: @Dcullen: There's slightly less to type and it's a preference thing. There is no technical reason.

Comment: @Dcullen Some people prefer this approach because it becomes a 1-liner. Chances are the original code will be more efficient than using `.find` in modern browsers, not that it would be a significant difference.

Comment: @KevinB: There would certainly be no measurable difference for a handful of calls. But I would think that this would be faster than the original because `#id` is recognized by jQuery and immediately forwarded to `document.getElementById` -- and apart from that, with `document.querySelectorAll` surely all other approaches will be in a dead heat?

Comment: Right, my point was that the original code won't run any reasonable amount slower or faster than any of the given answers, making it personal preference. I didn't quite word it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You can cache the object:

```
var $outer = $('#outer-element');
$outer.find('.first-class').html('wanna');
$outer.find('.second-class').html('scope');
$outer.find('.third-class').html('better');
```